# Can't install RMagick 4.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, rmagick

I'm running **Debian WSL 2** and I cannot install any version of RMagick.

I installed **imagemagick@6** via **homebrew** and after installation I saw following:

```
imagemagick@6 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have imagemagick@6 first in your PATH, run:
  echo 'export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find imagemagick@6 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/include"

For pkg-config to find imagemagick@6 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/imagemagick@6/lib/pkgconfig"
```

I followed all the instructions above

then I tried to install RMagick via **gem install rmagick -v '4.1.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'**
and got output:

```
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/ketch/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rmagick-4.1.2/ext/RMagick
/home/ketch/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.1/bin/ruby -I /home/ketch/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20211106-21975-1odkmjc.rb extconf.rb
checking for brew... yes
checking for Ruby version >= 2.3.0... yes
checking for pkg-config... yes


ERROR: Can't install RMagick 4.1.2. Can't find ImageMagick with pkg-config


*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/ketch/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.1/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/ketch/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/rmagick-4.1.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ketch/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rmagick-4.1.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ketch/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/rmagick-4.1.2/gem_make.out
```

I tried to install **rmagick** on my **WSL debian**,  **WSL ubuntu**, and on **Manjaro** through virtual machine, everytime the same error

Comment: »» Can't find ImageMagick with **pkg-config** «« : `# apt install libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev` ..... to get :  `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/{MagickWand-6.Q16.pc, MagickWand-im6.pc, MagickWand-im6.q16.pc, MagickWand.pc, Wand-6.Q16.pc, Wand-im6.pc, Wand.pc,, ImageMagick-6.Q16.pc, ImageMagick-im6.pc, ImageMagick-im6.q16.pc, ImageMagick.pc, MagickCore-6.Q16.pc, MagickCore-im6.pc, MagickCore.pc}` i.e. the required **pkgconfig** files.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Yes, there are really mentioned folders and files been created after I installed these packages, if I run "gem install rmagick" after that, nothing changes, but maybe I should now point out on some files with PKG_CONFIG_PATH variable or something?